# Padding or truncating a Python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'd like to truncate or pad a list. E.g. for size 4:

```
[1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,0]
[1,2,3,4,5] -> [1,2,3,4]
```

I can see a couple of ways:

```
def trp(l, n):
    """ Truncate or pad a list """
    r = l[:n]
    if len(r) < n:
        r.extend([0] * (n - len(r)))
    return r
```

Or a shorter, but less efficient:

```
map(lambda x, y: x if x else 0, m[0:n], [0] * n)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Slicing using an index greater than the length of a list just returns the entire list.

Multiplying a list by a negative value returns an empty list.

That means the function can be written as:

```
def trp(l, n):
    return l[:n] + [0]*(n-len(l))

trp([], 4)
[0, 0, 0, 0]

trp([1,2,3,4], 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

trp([1,2,3,4,5], 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

trp([1,2,3], 4)
[1, 2, 3, 0]
```

---

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3]

In [2]: a[:4]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: [0]*0
Out[3]: []

In [4]: [0]*-1
Out[4]: []
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use `itertools` module to make it completely lazy, like this

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain, islice
>>> def trimmer(seq, size, filler=0):
...     return islice(chain(seq, repeat(filler)), size)
... 
>>> list(trimmer([1, 2, 3], 4))
[1, 2, 3, 0]
>>> list(trimmer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here, we chain the actual sequence with the infinite repeater with the `filler` value. And then we slice the chained iterator to `size`.

So, when if the sequence has lesser number of elements than `size`, `chain` will start consuming the `repeat`. If the sequence has at least `size` elements, then `chain` will not even have to use the `repeat`.

The main advantage of this method is that, the complete trimmed or padded list is not created in memory, unless asked for it. So, if all you are going to do is to iterate it, then you can simply iterate it like this

```
>>> for item in trimmer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4):
...     print(item * 2)
...     
... 
2
4
6
8
```

Or, if you want to use it with another trimmed or padded list, then you can still do that without creating an actual list, like this

```
>>> for item in chain(trimmer([1, 2, 3], 4), trimmer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)):
...     print(item, item * 2)
...     
... 
1 2
2 4
3 6
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
```

Laziness Rocks ;-)

Comment: And, even better, this way you can just return the `islice` and let the caller decide whether he needs a list or can stay completely lazy all the way through.

Comment: @abarnert Ah, that is what I had in my mind actually :-) That is why I wrote "completely lazy" in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is substantially slower (2x - 3x slower) than the `trp` definition given by the OP.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Given that the OP asked for a more *elegant* solution, I don't really see that as a problem. Moreover you have to account that this is lazy, which in some circumstances may mean that it doesn't even get evaluated.

Answer (score 7):

In-place version:

```
l[n:] = [0] * (n - len(l))
```

Copy version:

```
l[:n] + [0] * (n - len(l))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy.pad) :

```
>>> def trp(a,n):
...    diff=n-len(a)
...    if diff >0:
...         return np.lib.pad(l2,(0,diff),'constant', constant_values=(0))
...    else :
...         return a[:n]
... 

>>> l1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2=[1, 2, 3]
>>> trp(l2,4)
array([1, 2, 3, 0])
>>> trp(l1,4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Numpy is seriously overkill for something like this unless OP is already using it.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Yeah its just an alternative! ;) also `np.pad` is more flexible and suggest a lot of tolls!

Answer (score 4):

I think your original version is not only very straightforward but also the most efficient one posted so far. I stored all answers given here in separate files (each of which exposing a 'trimmer' function) and then tested them for both padding as well as truncating. Here are the results:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Padding a list of 100 elements to 200 elements:

```
$ for VERSION in dmtri1 dmtri2 thefourtheye dting; do echo -n "$VERSION: "; python -m timeit -s "from $VERSION import trimmer; l = range(100)" -- 'list(trimmer(l, 200))'; done
dmtri1: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.9 usec per loop
dmtri2: 10000 loops, best of 3: 27.1 usec per loop
thefourtheye: 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.78 usec per loop
dting: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.69 usec per loop
```

Truncating a list of 100 elements to 50 elements:

```
$ for VERSION in dmtri1 dmtri2 thefourtheye dting; do echo -n "$VERSION: "; python -m timeit -s "from $VERSION import trimmer; l = range(100)" -- 'list(trimmer(l, 50))'; done
dmtri1: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.832 usec per loop
dmtri2: 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.27 usec per loop
thefourtheye: 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.62 usec per loop
dting: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 usec per loop
```

Comment: Vincent's in-place version will be faster, not that it matters.

Answer (score 1):

#### To append -

Append zeroes till your list reaches the length you need:

```
In [31]: x
Out[31]: [1, 2, 3, 0]

In [32]: [x.append(0) for i in range(10 - len(x))]
Out[32]: [None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Ignore the `None`s

```
In [33]: x
Out[33]: [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

#### To truncate

Use splicing:

```
In [19]: x
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [20]: x[:4]
Out[20]: [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a trivial solution. **Unpythonic.**

```
def f(a):
    length_a = len(a)
    limit = 4
    if length_a > limit:
      a = a[:limit]
    else:
      for i in xrange(0,limit - length_a):
        a.append(0)
    return a

>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,8]
>>> b = [1]
>>> c = [1,2]
>>> f(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> f(b)
[1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> f(c)
[1, 2, 0, 0]
```